# Working with processes in C

Tags: c, process

just a quick question regarding C and processes. In my program, I create another child process and use a two-directional pipe to communicate between the child and parent. The child calls execl() to run yet another program.

My question is: I want the parent to wait n amount of seconds and then check if the program that the child has run has exited (and with what status). Something like waitpid() but if the child doesn't exit in n seconds, I'd like to do something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` as option to poll, or register a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: the waitpid() route seems to be the best. is there a way that i can use waitpid() to get the exit value of the last child process? and i'm assuming that SIGCHLD runs the callback when a child exits?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alarm to interrupt waitpid() after N seconds (don't use this approach in a multithreaded environment though)

```
   signal(SIGALRM,my_dummy_handler);
   alarm(10);

   pid_t p = waitpid(...);
   if(p == -1) {
     if(errno == EINTR) {
        //timeout occured
      } else {
        //handle other error
     }
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm after :) Only problem is that if the process doesn't end, the code after waitpid() never gets run. How can I fix this?

Comment: or if that doesn't make sense, i want to return process control to the code after waitpid() so that it can kill the offending function